# Meaning of template syntax with scope qualifier

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, semantics

I saw this recently:

```
template <class U> struct ST
{
...
};
template <class U, class V>
struct ST<U V::*>
{
...
};
```

I assume that the second template is a specialization of the first.

But what is the semantics of `U V::*` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means "pointer-to-member of class `V` where the type of the member is `U` ". For instance,

```
struct X
{
    int x = 0;
};

// ...

int X::*p = &X::x;     // <== Declares p as pointer-to-member

ST<decltype(&X::x)> s; // <== Will instantiate your template specialization,
                       //     with U = int and V = X

ST<int X::*> t;        // <== Will instantiate your template specialization,
                       //     with U = int and V = X
```